# Notification Service on AWS S3 bucket (prefix) size

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

I have a specific use-case where we have a huge amount of data that is continuously streamed into the AWS bucket.

we want a notification service for **s3 bucket** on the specific folder where if a folder reaches specific size(for example 100 TB) a cleaning service should be triggered via (SNS, Aws lambda)

I have checked into AWS documentation. I did not found any direct support from Aws regarding this issue.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html

**We are planning to have a script that will periodically run and check the size of s3 Object and kicks AWS lambda.**

is there any elegant way to handle case like this .any suggestion or opinion is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Attach s3 trigger event to a lambda function which will get triggered, whenever any file is added to the S3 bucket.

Then in the lambda function check for the file size. This will eliminate to run a script periodically to check the size.

Below is a sample code for adding S3 trigger to a lambda function.

```
s3_trigger:
 handler: lambda/lambda.s3handler
 timeout: 900
 events:
   - s3:
       bucket: ${self:custom.sagemakerBucket}
       event: s3:ObjectCreated:*
       existing: true
       rules:
         - prefix: csv/
         - suffix: .csv
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct method for obtaining the size of a folder in Amazon S3 (because folders do not actually exist).

Here's a few ideas...

**Periodic Lambda function to calculate total**

Create an **Amazon CloudWatch Event** to trigger an AWS Lambda function at specific intervals. The Lambda function would list all objects with the given `Prefix` (effectively a folder) and total the sizes. If it exceeds 100TB, the Lambda function could trigger the cleaning process.

However, if there are thousands of files in that folder, this would be somewhat slow. Each API call can only retrieve 1000 objects. Thus, it might take many calls to count the total, and this would be done every checking interval.

**Keep a running total**

Configure **Amazon S3 Events** to trigger an AWS Lambda function whenever a new object is created with that `Prefix`. The Lambda function can retrieve increment the running total in a database. If the total exceeds 100TB, the Lambda function could trigger the cleaning process.

Which database to use? **Amazon DynamoDB** would be the quickest and it supports an 'increment' function, but you could be sneaky and just use AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store. This might cause a problem if new objects are created quickly because there's no locking. So, if files are coming in every few seconds or faster, definitely use DynamoDB.

**Slow motion**

You did not indicate how often this 100TB limit is likely to be triggered. If it only happens after a few days, you could use [Amazon S3 Inventory](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html), which provides a daily CSV containing a listing of objects in the bucket. This solution, of course, would not be applicable if the 100TB limit is hit in less than a day.